# Why does mount structure has two mountpoint fields?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

Im trying to understand how linux filesystem works. `struct mount` has `mnt_mountpoint` field, which points to the mountpoint dentry and used in path lookup.

```
struct mount {
    /*...*/
    struct dentry *mnt_mountpoint;
    /*...*/
    struct mountpoint *mnt_mp;
    /*...*/
}
```

At this point i dont understand what purpose of the second mountpoint field? It points to `mountpoint` structure, which, in turn, has pointer to another mountpoint dentry `m_dentry`.

```
struct mountpoint {
    struct hlist_node m_hash;
    struct dentry *m_dentry;
    struct hlist_head m_list;
    int m_count;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We also have struct mountpoint in the picture.  Once upon a time it used to be a part
>   of struct dentry - the list of all mounts on given mountpoint.  Since
>   it doesn't make sense to bloat every dentry for the sake of a very small
>   fraction that will ever be anyone's mountpoints, that thing got separated.
>
> What we have is
>
> - mark in dentry flags (`DCACHE_MOUNTED`) set for dentries that are
>     currently mountpoints
> - for each of those we have a struct mountpoint instance (exactly
>     one for each of those dentries).
>
> https://lwn.net/Articles/793073/

Instead of `struct dentry` having a list pointer, all the mountpoints are stored in a hash table.  The `m_dentry` field is used to distinguish different mountpoints that fall into the same hash bucket.

I guess `struct mount` holds a reference to `struct mountpoint` mostly for cleanup.  I.e. when `struct mount` is destroyed, we call `put_mountpoint(mnt_mp)`.  `m_count` is decremented, and if it reaches zero the mountpoint is destroyed.